# JX-RS 2.0 client API with Apache CFX 3.1.8 client implementation Thread Safety concern

Tags: java-ee-7, rest-client, cxf-client

I am writing REST client using JX-RS 2.0 client API and have Apache CXF 3.1.8 client as implementation in classpath.

My gradle dependency

```
compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-rs-client', version: '3.1.8'
```

I plan to client the Client instance with root url only once and use it to multiple create WebTarget at runtime as needed by the application. I want to reuse Client object because https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html this says it expensive operation to create and destroy client object.

```
String baseUrl = "http://localhost:9081/rest-service/rest/";

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
client.register(CustomObjectMapperProvider.class);
```

Use the client object to create WebTarget

```
WebTarget webTarget = client.target(baseUrl + path);
```

I understand that under the cover `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient` (the CXF's client implementation) is used. http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-ThreadSafety link says that both CXF WebClient and ProxyClient are not thread safe by default. As per this link there a threadSafe boolean flag that we can set to true while creating CXFs WebClient or ProxyClient.

In my code I want to use standard JX-RS 2.0 client APIs/interfaces and not CXF specific classes like WebClient or ProxyClient.

**Questions -**

1. If I instantiate the standard Client object using code above, is
   it thread safe? Is it ok to create it once and use it multiple time
   to WebTarget of different resources?
2. List item If it is not thread safe how to achieve thread safety where I want to reuse client object?